# Magento 2 Plugin afterGetPrice not working when catalog price rule applied

Tags: php, magento2

I created a simple Magento 2 plugin, which adds an additional cost to the price.

Here is my simple code that I tested

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Name]\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Model;

class Product
{
    protected $objectManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
        )
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }


    public function afterGetPrice(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject,
        $result
    ) {

        return $result + 100;

    }

}
```

This piece of code works fine, but when I create the catalog price rules the system is like it doesn't use it, but takes the price from another module.
Has anyone already encountered this problem and found a solution? I would like to understand and solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

In practice in module-catalog-rule/Model/Indexer/ProductPriceCalculator:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Indexer;

/**
 * Product price calculation according rules settings.
 */
class ProductPriceCalculator
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface
     */
    private $priceCurrency;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency)
    {
        $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates product price.
     *
     * @param array $ruleData
     * @param null $productData
     * @return float
     */
    public function calculate($ruleData, $productData = null)
    {
        if ($productData !== null && isset($productData['rule_price'])) {
            $productPrice = $productData['rule_price'];
        } else {
            $productPrice = $ruleData['default_price'];
        }

        switch ($ruleData['action_operator']) {
            case 'to_fixed':
                $productPrice = min($ruleData['action_amount'], $productPrice);
                break;
            case 'to_percent':
                $productPrice = $productPrice * $ruleData['action_amount'] / 100;
                break;
            case 'by_fixed':
                $productPrice = max(0, $productPrice - $ruleData['action_amount']);
                break;
            case 'by_percent':
                $productPrice = $productPrice * (1 - $ruleData['action_amount'] / 100);
                break;
            default:
                $productPrice = 0;
        }

        return $this->priceCurrency->round($productPrice);
    }
}
```

The calculate function ($ruleData, $ProductData = null) performs the calculations set in the catalog rule.

The real problem lies in $ruleData, because the price information it contains is taken directly from the product_catalog database, excluding any plugin designed to modify the price.

I personally don't know, if this is a Magento 2 bug or not, but the only way to make the module catalog rule work is just to intercept that variable and modify its contents.

I hope it helps someone. :)

Ps. sorry for my bad English